# Unit test Actions on Google Dialogflow locally

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, chatbot, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I'm trying to unit test a `DialogflowApp` locally by using the firebase shell environment. (in a cli do firebase experimental:functions:shell and then call my methods)

I have followed this guide by google https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator but they don't use the DialogflowApp where the invoked function tries to bind a request object containing intents and parameters like this ->

```
exports.myFunction = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
const app = new App({ request, response });

function myMethod(app) {
    let myArgument = app.getArgument(MY_ARGUMENT);
    app.tell('Here we are responding');
}

let actionMap = new Map();
actionMap.set(MYMETHOD_ACTION, myMethod);

app.handleRequest(actionMap);
});
```

Regardless of what request object I send in the CLI, like this `myFunction(require("../test/testdata.json"))`, the request body object is empty, like this `body: {}` which means I can't do `app.handleRequest()` or `app.getArgument()`. The error message I get is

> RESPONSE RECEIVED FROM FUNCTION: 400, Action Error: no matching intent
>   handler for: null

I thought that if I populated testdata.json with the json request data shown in Actions on Google -> console.actions.google.com -> Simulator it would be valid data but no.

My question is, how can i mock my request data so that I can start unit testing my fullfillment methods locally?

EDIT 1:

```
firebase > myMethod.post("/").form(require("../test/testdata.json"))
Sent request to function.
firebase > info: User function triggered, starting execution
info: Function crashed
info: TypeError: Cannot destructure property `parameters` of 'undefined' or 'null'.
```

if we look in dialogflow_app.js we can see this code for fetching an argument value

```
  getArgument (argName) {
    debug('getArgument: argName=%s', argName);
    if (!argName) {
      error('Invalid argument name');
      return null;
    }
    const { parameters } = this.body_.result;
    if (parameters && parameters[argName]) {
      return parameters[argName];
    }
    return this.getArgumentCommon(argName);
  }
```

this.body_ is always just empty `{}`, regardless of how and what I send into the method when running locally.

EDIT 3

```
firebase > myMethod({method: "post",json: true, body:  require("../test/testdata.json")})
```

Sent request to function.
firebase > info: User function triggered, starting execution
info: Function crashed
info: TypeError: Cannot destructure property `parameters` of 'undefined' or 'null'.

Comment: it is not clear on your code if the variable MYMETHOD_ACTION has a value. What I could understand from the error message is that it could not find an match between the action and any method to handle the request. Can you double check if this variable has a value setted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Invoking a Firebase HTTPS function using the shell requires a [different form](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator#invoke_https_functions). It takes the parameters that the request module does, so in order to emulate a webhook, it will be something like this:

```
myfunction({
  method: 'POST',
  json: true,
  body: require("../test/testdata.json")
});
```

These three parameters are important:

- You need to specify that this is a POST operation
- You need to indicate that the body will be JSON. This will send the correct header and won't try to send the body as x-www-form-urlencoded
- You need to include the body. As an object is ok because you've set the json parameter to true.

Comment: Hi and thanks for the reply. I have tried to follow the guides but regardless of how I do I get the same error. Please see the Edited question for the shell commands I use.

Comment: Did you test it using the exact code that I suggested?

Comment: Clarified why I used the parameters I did.

Comment: Hi, I have tested with your exact example as well, see Edit 3.

Comment: Hi, sorry for saying it didn't work. It seems that after I did firebase experimental:functions:shell the CLI didn't care if I updated testdata.json which made me think that body never was set. You were right all along. Thanks!

Comment: That is actually a side-effect of node. Once you require() something, the results are cached. Glad this works!